# How to make an asynchronous self-calling loop non-recursive

Tags: php, asynchronous, functional-programming, promise

I'm writing a function in PHP that loops through an array, and then performs an asynchronous call on it (using a Promise).

The problem is that, the only way I can make this loop happen, is by letting a function call itself asynchronously. I run into the 100-nested functions problem really quick, and I would basically like to change it to not recur.

```
function myloop($data, $index = 0) {

    if (!isset($data[$index])) {
        return;
    }

    $currentItem = $data[$index];
    $currentItem()->then(function() use ($data, $index) {
       myloop($data, $index + 1);   
    });

}
```

For those that want to answer this from a practical perspective (e.g.: rewrite to not be asynchronous), I'm experimenting with functional and asynchronous patterns and I want to know if it is possible to do this with PHP.

Comment: Wouldn't using a Generator be better in this case? How are you actually implementing your promise? I'm assuming you have a promise class that implements then() by dumping the callback on a stack? And then subsequently firing a resolve() method?

Comment: @MarkBaker: If it's better to use generators, I would love to know! Not sure with what you mean about dumping a callback on a stack, but my promise class is here: https://github.com/fruux/sabre-event/blob/master/lib/Promise.php

Comment: P.S. In my actual use-case $data is a generator, but I stripped it from the example as I felt it made things more complicated.

Comment: @MarkBaker: I figured out what you meant with your question. then() is called immediately if the promise is already resolved. The problem only occurs if all the promises in the loop are already resolved.

Comment: You should return the `myloop` call from the `then` an then return also from the `!isset`, a promise represents a value. Also, having already resolved promises execute `.then` immediately is extremely broken - switch implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a possible solution in pseudo-code.  The idea is to limit 
the number of items running asynchronous at once by using a database 
queue.  `myloop()` is no longer directly recursive, instead being called
whenever an item finishes running.   In the sample data, I've limited it
to 4 items concurrently (arbitrary value).
Basically, it's still recursively calling itself, but in a roundabout way,
avoiding the situation you mentioned of many nested called.

Execution Flow:

```
myloop() ---> queue
^              v
|              |
'<-processor <-'
```

---

```
<?php    
//----------
// database

//table:  config
//columns: setting, value
//items:    ACTIVE_COUNT, 0
//          ITEM_CONCURRENT_MAX, 4
//table: queue
//columns: id, item, data, index, pid, status(waiting, running, finished), locked
//  --- end pseudo-schema ---

<?php    
// ---------------
// itemloop.php
// ---------------

//sends an item and associated data produced by myloop() into a database queue,
//to be processed (run asynchronous, but limited to how many can run at once) 
function send_item_to_processor($item, $data, $index, $counter) { 
   //INSERT $item to a queue table, along with $data, $index (if needed), $counter, locked = 0
   //status == waiting
}

//original code, slightly modified to remove direct recursion and implement 
//the queue.
function myloop($data, $index = 0, $counter = 0) {

    if (!isset($data[$index])) {
        return;
    }

    $currentItem = $data[$index];
    $currentItem()->then(function() use ($data, $index) {
       //instead of directly calling `myloop()`, push item to
       //database and let the processor worry about it. see below.
       //*if you wanted currentItem to call a specific function after finishing,
       //you could create an array of numbered functions and pass the function
       //number along with the other data.* 
       send_item_to_processor($currentItem, $data, $index + 1, $counter + 1);
    });

}


// ---------------
// processor.php
// ---------------

//handles the actual running of items.  looks for a "waiting" item and 
//executes it, updating various statuses along the way. 
//*called from `process_queue()`*
function process_new_items() { 
   //select ACTIVE_COUNT, ITEM_CONCURRENT_MAX
   //ITEM_COUNT = total records in the queue. this is done to
   //short-circuit the execution of `process_queue()` whenever possible
   //(which is called frequently).
   if (ITEM_COUNT == 0 || $ACTIVE_COUNT >= $ITEM_CONCURRENT_MAX) 
     return FALSE;
   //select item from queue where status = waiting AND locked = 0 limit 1;
   //update item set status = running, pid = programPID
   //update config ACTIVE_COUNT = +1
   //**** asynchronous run item here ****//
   return TRUE;
}  

//main processor for the queue.  first processes new/waiting items
//if it can (if too many items aren't already running), then processes
//dead/completed items.  Upon an item.status == finished, `myloop()` is
//called from this function.  Still technically a recursive call, but 
//avoids out-of-control situations due to the asynchronous nature.    
//this function could be called on a timer of some sort, such as a cronjob
function process_queue() {
  if (!process_new_items()) 
    return FALSE;  //too many instances running, no need to process

  //check queue table for items with status == finished or is_pid_valid(pid) == FALSE
  $numComplete = count($rows);
  //update all rows to locked = 1, in case process_queue() gets called again before
  //we finish, resulting in an item potentially being processed as dead twice. 
  foreach($rows as $item) {
    if (is_invalid(pid) || $status == finished)  { 
       //and here is the call back to myloop(), avoiding a strictly recursive 
       //function call.  
       //*Not sure what to do with `$item` here -- might be passed back to `myloop()`?.*
       //delete item(s) from queue
       myloop(data, index, counter - 1);
       //decrease config.ACTIVE_COUNT by $numComplete
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Trick, I was mainly wondering if it was theoretically possible to rewrite my function into one that doesn't use recursion. Using a second function (a loop function) does make this super easy, but I wanted to avoid that.